Buyer deposit for house sold as is
Buyer did inspection on old house. Inspection advised that all major systems are end of life. Also advised to inspect fireplace before use. Buyers bargained down the price and signed addendum to say house sold as is and signed to drop all contingencies.
A few days before closing there is a gas leak from fireplace key. Seller called gas company and shut down gas. Seller disclosed this to buyers. Can buyers walk with their deposit? Or does “as is” cover it. In California.

How would that contradict "major systems are end of life" (which the buyer used to drive down the price)? It's not new information, but confirmatory. The "inspect fireplace before use" even draws attention to its state.

In any case, a leaking gas key isn't a major failing: just a minor repair item.

@WeatherVane, but is it enough to let someone with buyer's remorse walk away from a sale with no penalty?

IANAL, but I don't see why it would. "As is" doesn't mean "with only the problems identified during the inspection".

@Barmar no, "as is" is "with all found and not found problems, in the exact state that it is in when the deal is signed."

@Trish That's what I said: not just the found problems.


Can buyers walk with their deposit? Or does “as is” cover it.

Ultimately, this should be spelled out clearly in the written contract as amended.
Usually, in this situation, the buyers are faced with a choice. They can either go forward with the purchase at the amended purchase price, and receive credit for the deposit, or can refuse to close and forfeit their deposit as liquidated damages for not closing.

A few days before closing there is a gas leak from fireplace key.
Seller called gas company and shut down gas.

The seller has a duty to disclose known material latent defects in the house. If this was a defect that could not have been discovered by reasonable inspection but was known to the seller before the inspection objection deadline or the agreed new amendment to the contract, the Buyer might be entitled to get the deposit back if the buyer didn't close. (If the buyer closed knowing about the defect, there is a good chance that the contract would "merge into the deed", which means that the buyer would not have a right to sue the seller for non-disclosure, although I haven't reviewed the recent California case law on point.)
Strictly speaking, if there was seller liability under these circumstances, it might very well be for fraud rather than for a breach of contract.
But, if this problem is not material, or could have been discovered with a reasonable inspection, or if the problem was not known to the seller, or more than one of these things was true, then the buyer must close at the agreed price or forfeit the buyer's deposit.
The question doesn't clarify whether the final problem could have been discovered with a reasonable inspection, or when the seller discovered it. It also isn't clear to me if this defect is a material one. If it takes a quick one time visit from a plumber and a $30 part to fix, it probably isn't a material defect. If it is a $30,000 problem, it probably is a material defect. So, it is impossible to know the outcome from the information in the question alone.
